# how to install ipa file in iphone using windows without developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ipa

I have created an ipa file using codemagic, when I am trying to install in my iphone using itunes, it is giving error, 'unable to install, because its integrity could not be verified',
I don't have developer account, I don't have mac, And I haven't done any specific configuration related to ios, Just I need to test this app in my iphone using windows,
is there any way to do this

Comment: Only owners of developer account can create ad-hoc mobile provision profile with your's phone UDID and sign dev version of ipa. Pay for account or meet somebody having account. Give him a beer, because he has only 100 slots for development phones per year.